# Character array of size 10 displays 11 characters when printed using %s

Tags: c, arrays, linux, string

I have tried to solve the mystery in this code but in vain. The following program is for printing the length and the line from the input. It has a MAX limit of 10 characters and for lines with greater than 10 characters it counts all the characters but stores only 10.

What baffles me is that in the output, when a line of greater than 10 characters is fed as input, it prints the first 11 characters of the input, when I'm storing the line in an array of 10 characters size. How is it possible?

I'm using GCC Compiler in Linux Mint.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#define MAX 10

int Getline(char arr[], int lim);

void main(){
    int len=0;
    char c=0;
    char line[MAX]={};

    len=Getline(line,MAX);
    printf("%d\n%s",len,line);
    printf("\nDo you want to continue?\t");

    while((c=getchar())=='y'){
        len=Getline(line,MAX);
        printf("\n%d\n%s",len,line);
        printf("\nDo you want to continue?\t");
    }
}

int Getline(char line[], int lim){
    int i=0;
    while((line[i]=getchar())!='\n' && i<lim){
        i++;
    }

    if(line[i]=='\n' && i<lim)   
    {
        line[i]='\0'; // This is line[lim+1]
        return i;
    }
    else if(i==lim){
    while(getchar()!='\n')
    i++;
    return i+1;
    }
}
```

The input and output is as shown below and I use gcc compiler in linux mint.

OUTPUT:

```
Queen
5
Queen
Do you want to continue?        yQueenOfDragons

14
QueenOfDrag
Do you want to continue?        y123456789012345

15
12345678901
Do you want to continue?        yYouKnowNothingJonSnow

21
YouKnowNoth
Do you want to continue?        n
```

Also when i interchange the test conditions in while loop as follows

```
while(i<lim && (line[i]=getchar())!='\n')
```

It prints a strange '@' character after printing the first 10 characters, when the line length exceeds the limit. The output is given below

OUTPUT 2:

```
Queen
5
Queen
Do you want to continue?        yQueenOfDragons

13
QueenOfDra@
Do you want to continue?        y12345678901

10
1234567890@
Do you want to continue?        yYouKnowNothingJonSnow

20
YouKnowNot@
Do you want to continue?        n
```

Kindly explain the strange behaviour. Thanks in advance!

PS: This is exercise 1-16 from 'The C Programming Language' by Dennis M Ritchie and Brian Kernighan.

Comment: Printing stops at terminator not at end of array.

Comment: the terminator is '\0' character is suppose, but explain how is it that everytime it stops at the 11th character? and how does it print the 11th character when I'm not even storing it? Also, when the condition is interchanged explain why the '@' symbol is printed after 10 characters ?

Comment: Not having a null byte will cause whatever bytes are after the array to be printed. Since this is undefined behavior, you can't reason about it and gain anything meaningful.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect it's printing the 11th character because of this while expression:

```
while((line[i]=getchar())!='\n' && i<lim){
  i++;
}
```

When `i < lim` returns false, you have already put the result of `getchar()` in `line[i]`.

Also, remember to always leave room for and complete strings with the null terminator. `Getline(line, lim)` does not always put a null-terminated string at `line`.

Answer (score 1):

Your program invokes undefined behavior for long inputs at the following line by accessing `line[i]`:

```
while((line[i]=getchar())!='\n' && i<lim){
```

You can see this for yourself [here](https://taas.trust-in-soft.com/tsnippet/t/b0493653).

Since `line` points to an array of size `lim`, you should simply test whether `i<lim` **before** writing to `line[i]`:

```
while(i<lim && (line[i]=getchar())!='\n'){
```

Fixing that problem shows the same issue a few lines later ([link](https://taas.trust-in-soft.com/tsnippet/t/8805a17c)):

```
if(line[i]=='\n' && i<lim)
```

After fixing that too, there remains the problem that you are passing to `printf("%s",…` the address of an array of characters that is not zero-terminated ([link](https://taas.trust-in-soft.com/tsnippet/t/d2df05fc)).

Answer (score 0):

I made some changes to your code

```
#include<stdio.h>
#define MAX 10

int Getline(char arr[], int lim);

void main(){
    int len=0;
    char c=0;
    char line[MAX]={};

    len=Getline(line,MAX);
    printf("%d\n%s",len,line);
    printf("\nDo you want to continue?\t");

    while((c=getchar())=='y'){
        len=Getline(line,MAX);
        printf("\n%d\n%s",len,line);
        printf("\nDo you want to continue?\t");
    }
}

int Getline(char line[], int lim){
    int i=0;
    while((line[i]=getchar())!='\n' && i<lim){
        i++;
    }

    if(line[i]=='\n' && i<lim)   
    {
        line[i]='\0'; // This is line[lim+1]
        return i;
    }
    else if(i==lim){
    line[lim] = '\0'; //Change is being made here adding terminator to string
    while(getchar()!='\n')
    i++;
    return i+1;
    }
}
```

Explanation: 
In string are read till null pointer i.e. '\0'. Since you were declaring it in string in case size was greater than 10, it showed such behaviour

Although I recommend practice of declaring string of size max+1 so that any possibility of overflow is omitted

Because in a string of size 10, there should be 9 characters and 1 null character

Comment: Your version still contains undefined behavior: https://taas.trust-in-soft.com/tsnippet/t/0e798040